What's this movie with a network of anonymous party organizers?
OK so the movie starts at a cafe or something, two guys are somehow chatting while they don't know each other. They have their phones on the table. One leaves in a hurry and picks up his stuff and goes. The other one does the same, but notices that they accidentally swapped their phones.
So he doesn't know his name and hence can't contact the guy to swap the phones again. (I know he could call his own number but I don't remember why he doesn't).
The phone (that is not his) rings, and a woman calls and says something like 'Are you available tonight?'. After some time, the guy accepts and goes, in fact the woman, while refusing to give her name, sets up the whole dinner, hotel room, pays for everything. They have a nice time and the next day she vanishes and he can't contact her ever again.
This is some kind of network of people that have each other's number, they call and set up the night, and the called person doesn't have to do anything but enjoy the night. All of this is anonymous. Then the main character would fall in love with a woman and tries to see her again. Or something :)
This is very vague in my memory, but hopefully some of the information is correct and one may know that movie and its title.

Year of release? Genre? Country of origin?

In the past 15 years I'd say. Love story.

Well that was fast.
Looks like Deception (2008). Starring Hugh Jackman, Ewan McGregor, and Michelle Williams.

Timid accountant Jonathan McQuarry (Ewan McGregor) is an auditor
  working out of New York. One night while working late in a boardroom
  he meets a charismatic lawyer, Wyatt Bose (Hugh Jackman), who
  befriends him over a joint. After a long conversation, Jonathan takes
  the subway home where he has a brief encounter with a blonde woman
  (Michelle Williams) while waiting on the train. Upon returning home he
  notices a pipe in his bedroom is leaking and leaving a stain.
Jonathan contacts Wyatt the next day and they play tennis after work.
  They meet again for lunch the next day and upon leaving, Wyatt takes
  Jonathan's mobile phone instead of his own, forcing a trade. He
  mentions he will be in London on business for the next few weeks. When
  Jonathan realizes the phones have been switched he attempts to contact
  Wyatt but does not reach him. He is soon contacted by a woman (Natasha
  Henstridge) who asks if he is free that night. He informs her that he
  is and agrees to meet her. When she arrives, they proceed directly to
  a hotel room upstairs and have sex. In the morning, Jonathan realizes
  that Wyatt must be on some type of exclusive sex club list.
When Wyatt calls the next day, he encourages Jonathan to stay on the
  list. Jonathon has an encounter with an older woman (Charlotte
  Rampling) who explains more of the list's rules: the initiator pays
  for the room, no names are exchanged, there is no rough play.
  Participants are always anonymous, although Jonathan later spots the
  older woman on the cover of Forbes. Over the next few weeks, he has
  anonymous encounters with several women.
One night after initiating another encounter, Jonathan is surprised to
  find that his partner is the blond woman he met while waiting for the
  train. He tells her that they had met once before, and instead of
  having sex, they order room service and talk for hours. The woman does
  not say her name, but Jonathan assumes that it begins with an "S"
  because of an S-shaped pendant on her handbag. The next day Jonathan
  rejects other callers from the list but when "S" calls again they
  agree to meet for dinner in Chinatown. They then proceed to a hotel
  where she requests some ice. When Jonathan returns to the room she is
  gone and there is blood on the bedsheets. Someone knocks him out from
  behind, but when he wakes up again the bed has been made. He contacts
  the police and explains to the Detective (Lisa Gay Hamilton) that "S"
  is missing but that he has little to no information about her. She
  doubts his story, thinking that he is delusional. Jonathan tries to
  trace Wyatt, but Wyatt's boss and landlady claim not to know him.

Rest of the summary at the above link.

Impressive. Wow. Thanks. Did you know it or am I that bad at searching?

This movie is from 2008. Sorry I misled you with such a large time span.

I googled the swapped phones part. First result was a Nigerian comedy called "Phone Swap" (go figure). "Deception" was a bit farther down.

Well done. It seems that I forgot most of the plot. Which is good: I think I know what I'm going to watch next! Thanks again.

I just saw this a few weeks ago.  Good flick.
